# How to create customized subfolders and save email attachments to those folders which are stored on my PC?

Tags: vba, outlook

Currently, the code below which I got from ([Save attachments from multiple selected items in Outlook (VBA)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Save-attachments-from-5b6bf54b)) takes the emails I select, asks me where to save the email attachments and saves the attachments as named in the emails to the folder I selected.

The problem is, if I select multiple emails, there is no way of telling which email the attachments are associated to.

Would it be possible to have it so when I select where to save the attachments that the script creates a sub folder for each email and then puts the attachments in that folder? I'd like to use the `SenderName` for each sub folder name and add the date to the end of it? Example, `"SubFolderXYZ_04-30-2018"`.

Also, is there a way to make it so that the date on the sub-folder matches the date that the email was received, instead of "today's" date?

```
Option Explicit

If VBA7 Then
    Private lHwnd As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Else
    Private lHwnd As Long    
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
End If

' The class name of Outlook window.  
Private Const olAppCLSN As String = "rctrl_renwnd32"
' Windows desktop - the virtual folder that is the root of the namespace.  
Private Const CSIDL_DESKTOP = &H0
' Only return file system directories. If the user selects folders that are not part of the file system, the OK button is grayed.  
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1
' Do not include network folders below the domain level in the dialog box's tree view control.  
Private Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = &H2
' The maximum length for a path is 260 characters.  
Private Const MAX_PATH = 260

'  Returns the number of attachements in the selection.  
Public Function SaveAttachmentsFromSelection() As Long
Dim objFSO              As Object       ' Computer's file system object.  
Dim objShell            As Object       ' Windows Shell application object.  
Dim objFolder           As Object       ' The selected folder object from Browse for Folder dialog box.  
Dim objItem             As Object       ' A specific member of a Collection object either by position or by key.  
Dim selItems            As Selection    ' A collection of Outlook item objects in a folder.  
Dim atmt                As Attachment   ' A document or link to a document contained in an Outlook item.  
Dim strAtmtPath         As String       ' The full saving path of the attachment.  
Dim strAtmtFullName     As String       ' The full name of an attachment.  
Dim strAtmtName(1)      As String       ' strAtmtName(0): to save the name; strAtmtName(1): to save the file extension. They are separated by dot of an attachment file name.  
Dim strAtmtNameTemp     As String       ' To save a temporary attachment file name.  
Dim intDotPosition      As Integer      ' The dot position in an attachment name.  
Dim atmts               As Attachments  ' A set of Attachment objects that represent the attachments in an Outlook item.  
Dim lCountEachItem      As Long         ' The number of attachments in each Outlook item.  
Dim lCountAllItems      As Long         ' The number of attachments in all Outlook items.  
Dim strFolderPath       As String       ' The selected folder path.  
Dim blnIsEnd            As Boolean      ' End all code execution.  
Dim blnIsSave           As Boolean      ' Consider if it is need to save.  

blnIsEnd = False
blnIsSave = False
lCountAllItems = 0

On Error Resume Next

Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

If Err.Number = 0 Then

    ' Get the handle of Outlook window.  
    lHwnd = FindWindow(olAppCLSN, vbNullString)

    If lHwnd <> 0 Then

        ' /* Create a Shell application object to pop-up BrowseForFolder dialog box. */  
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(lHwnd, "Select folder to save attachments:", _
                                                 BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, CSIDL_DESKTOP)

        ' /* Failed to create the Shell application. */  
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Run-time error '" & CStr(Err.Number) & " (0x" & CStr(Hex(Err.Number)) & ")':" & vbNewLine & _
                   Err.Description & ".", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
            blnIsEnd = True
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
        End If

        If objFolder Is Nothing Then
            strFolderPath = ""
            blnIsEnd = True
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
        Else
            strFolderPath = CGPath(objFolder.Self.Path)

            ' /* Go through each item in the selection. */  
            For Each objItem In selItems
                lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count

                ' /* If the current item contains attachments. */  
                If lCountEachItem > 0 Then
                    Set atmts = objItem.Attachments

                    ' /* Go through each attachment in the current item. */  
                    For Each atmt In atmts

                        ' Get the full name of the current attachment.  
                        strAtmtFullName = atmt.FileName

                        ' Find the dot postion in atmtFullName.  
                        intDotPosition = InStrRev(strAtmtFullName, ".")

                        ' Get the name.  
                        strAtmtName(0) = Left$(strAtmtFullName, intDotPosition - 1)
                        ' Get the file extension.
                        strAtmtName(1) = Right$(strAtmtFullName, Len(strAtmtFullName) - intDotPosition)
                        ' Get the full saving path of the current attachment.  
                        strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & atmt.FileName

                        ' /* If the length of the saving path is not larger than 260 characters.*/  
                        If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH Then
                            ' True: This attachment can be saved.  
                            blnIsSave = True

                            ' /* Loop until getting the file name which does not exist in the folder. */  
                            Do While objFSO.FileExists(strAtmtPath)
                                strAtmtNameTemp = strAtmtName(0) & _
                                                  Format(Now, "_mm-dd-yyyy")
                                strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & strAtmtNameTemp & "." & strAtmtName(1)

                                ' /* If the length of the saving path is over 260 characters.*/  
                                If Len(strAtmtPath) > MAX_PATH Then
                                    lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                                    ' False: This attachment cannot be saved.  
                                    blnIsSave = False
                                    Exit Do
                                End If
                            Loop

                            ' /* Save the current attachment if it is a valid file name. */  
                            If blnIsSave Then atmt.SaveAsFile strAtmtPath
                        Else
                            lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                ' Count the number of attachments in all Outlook items.  
                lCountAllItems = lCountAllItems + lCountEachItem
            Next
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed to get the handle of Outlook window!", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
        blnIsEnd = True
        GoTo PROC_EXIT
    End If

' /* For run-time error:  
'    The Explorer has been closed and cannot be used for further operations.  
'    Review your code and restart Outlook. */  
Else
    MsgBox "Please select an Outlook item at least.", vbExclamation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    blnIsEnd = True
End If

PROC_EXIT:
SaveAttachmentsFromSelection = lCountAllItems

' /* Release memory. */  
If Not (objFSO Is Nothing) Then Set objFSO = Nothing
If Not (objItem Is Nothing) Then Set objItem = Nothing
If Not (selItems Is Nothing) Then Set selItems = Nothing
If Not (atmt Is Nothing) Then Set atmt = Nothing
If Not (atmts Is Nothing) Then Set atmts = Nothing

' /* End all code execution if the value of blnIsEnd is True. */  
If blnIsEnd Then End
End Function

' Convert general path.  
Public Function CGPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    CGPath = Path
End Function

' Run this macro for saving attachments.  
Public Sub ExecuteSaving()
    Dim lNum As Long

    lNum = SaveAttachmentsFromSelection

    If lNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully.", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attachment(s) in the selected Outlook items.", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To get the date email was received work with [MailItem.ReceivedTime Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-receivedtime-property-outlook) then format it like this **`Format(objItem.ReceivedTime, "DD-MM-YYYY")`***

*for the folder use basic function that will check if folder exist else create one using [MailItem.SenderName Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-sendername-property-outlook)*

*Example*

```
Private Function CreateDir(strFolderPath As String)
    Dim Elm As Variant
    Dim CheckPath As String

    CheckPath = ""
    For Each Elm In Split(strFolderPath, "\")
        CheckPath = CheckPath & Elm & "\"

        Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Exist"

        If Len(Dir(CheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir CheckPath
            Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Created"
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

In your code  make these changes

> ```
> ' /* Go through each item in the selection. */
> For Each objItem In selItems
>
>     Dim ResetPath As String
>         ResetPath = strFolderPath
>
>     strFolderPath = strFolderPath & objItem.SenderName & "_" & _
>                              Format(objItem.ReceivedTime, "DD-MM-YYYY")
>
>     CreateDir strFolderPath
>
>     lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count
> ```

*And this should be*

> ```
> strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & "\" & atmt.FileName
> ```

*And the following*

> ```
>     ' Count the number of attachments in all Outlook items.
>     lCountAllItems = lCountAllItems + lCountEachItem
>     strFolderPath = ResetPath ' reset
> Next
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response and help, @0m3r! I'm getting a Compile error with line:  `CreateDir strFolderPath`. I tried adding a `=` and then a `&` in the middle but it didn't like that either.

Comment: Don't need the full code, sorry. I had copied & paste wrong the Private Function part, my bad! The code you added works perfect and will help me a lot, thank you!